# .htaccess redirect a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am in need of help with build an htaccess file. Basically I am moving an website from www.abc.com to www.xyz.com. Now, here is the two things that I am trying to achieve:

- All users should be redirected to `www.xyz.com` when accessing `www.abc.com`
- If user accesses `www.abc.com/files/abcd.file` or `www.abc.com/files/folder/abcd.file`, etc. should be redirected to `arhive.xyz.com/abcd.file`, etc. Basicly, this URL `www.abc.com/files/`, should be replaced with `arhive.xyz.com`, keeping the same file/directory structure.

Someone can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several requirements, but *if I understand correctly* this should get what you need in the htaccess file in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Of course change to your domain names.